# Can't find replacement nozzle tube

Tags: monoprice-maker-select

I have a Monoprice Maker Select Plus.

It recently started having issues printing. It turns out that the small plastic tube that feeds the extruder with filament was completely clogged. I couldn't get any of the filament out so I need a new feeder tube. I can't find one specifically for this printer anywhere. Does anyone have any ideas?[image]

Comment: Could you add a photograph? Is this tube inside the heat break or between extruder and hotend?

Comment: I just added a picture. It is a plastic tube that goes inside of the metal tube I circled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This printer is using a so-called MK 10 extruder/hotend. These are a little different, there is a liner for the heat break that continues all the way down to inside the MK 10 nozzle:

[image]

This PTFE tubular liner has an outer dimension of 4 mm and an inner diameter of 2 mm. The length of the tube is 34 mm. These tubes can be bought at pre-cut size or, more economical, bought per meter.

Comment: The per meter tube looks like one of the sizse sold for Bowden tubes.

Comment: It is one and the same material, it's a PTFE tube ID/OD 2/4 mm. Alternatives are Capricorn tubes, which supposed to withstand higher temperatures.

Comment: PTFE has an advantage of low friction as well has temperature tolerance; thus ideal for Bowden tubes.  Apparently, Capricorn tubes are still PTFE.

Comment: Any idea where I can buy this? Everywhere I find it, it is 1.75mm.

Comment: @sabo It's designed for 1.75mm filament, the ID will still be large enough to work flawlessly.

Comment: @sabo Online 3D print webshops, online market places, Chinese selling platforms, etc. I get my tubes from AliExpress, cheap, but you need to wait a few weeks or months. 2/4 mm PTFE tube is very common, it shouldn't be hard to find it in your city/country (more expensive but fast). You shouldn't buy too tight tubes, but 1.9/4 will work also for 1.75 mm filament.